# How to pass string as parameter to API from powershell within API Body

Tags: powershell

I am trying to pass multi line string as parameter to API from powershell. But the FromBody in API reads the parameter as null.

Below is my powershell script:

```
$obj = "{""TestCase"":{"
$obj = $obj + "`n""tc_name"":TestCase1"""
$obj = $obj + "}"
$obj = $obj + "`n""}"

$obj

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:65452/api/e10/e10PostTCData -Method Post -Body $obj
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

When the data is sent in API body it should be prefixed with "=".

$obj = "{""TestCase"":{"
$obj = $obj + "`n""tc_name"":TestCase1"""
$obj = $obj + "}"
$obj = $obj + "`n""}"

$obj

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:65452/api/e10/e10PostTCData -Method Post -Body =$obj